# Do the hits from Lulu's passive (Pix) proc on-hit effects or count for number of hits?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering if Pix's 3 hits count for things like Ionic Spark or proc the effects of Wit's End. If nothing else, does Spell Vamp proc off of their dmg?

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't apply on-hit effects or procs. Nor does it give spell vamp. It is just a little extra damage, and that's all. I have played her AP, I know first hand with spell vamp and rylias (on hit effect).

**Edit:** this is backed up by the LoL Wikia as well: [[1]](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress/Ability_Details)

Comment: People are much more likely to upvote you if you back up your answer with sources.

Comment: Well I play her, so I know first hand. NBD though.

Comment: @Agilism What rapida means is that if you provide your reasoning why you think / know this, users are more likely to up vote / believe your answer. So editing your post to include that you know this since you play her would count as "including sources".

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I'm not arguing the point. Facts need proof to be facts.

Comment: I added the wikia link that state non effect of on hit effect and spell vamp effect.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't. Pix is counted as a separate unit, which is why you can attach it to other people.